# Cosa significa "parlare serrato"?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*, di Erri De Luca, ho letto:

> Non vi piaceva quella novità. Bisognava andare a scuola più veloci perché era 
>   lontana, ritornare di corsa per non tardare a pranzo, studiare più in fretta. Non che 
>   fossi lento, ma ero calmo. Seguivo male chi **parlava serrato**.

Ho cercato l'aggettivo "serrato" nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/serrato1) ma, tra le differenti accezioni che ho trovato, non riesco a vedere a quale corrisponda l'espressione "parlare serrato". Significa parlare con la boca chiusa? Vuol dire "parlare velocemente"? Il senso sarebbe quello di "parlare in modo conciso e con un’argomentazione solida e stringente"? Significa avere una pronuncia chiusa?

Comment: Lo interpreto con tutta  probabilità "parlare velocemente". Si può dire anche "parlare fitto".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Parlare serrato” significa, in questo contesto, parlare in modo veloce, incalzante, senza pause. Possiamo comprenderlo dal contesto in cui la frase è inserita; il protagonisa preferisce fare le cose con calma e non si trova a proprio agio nelle attività che richiedono velocità (andare e tornare da scuola, seguire discorsi veloci).

Answer (score 4):

Lo Zanichelli da le seguenti definizioni di serrato:

> (fig.) ***Stringato, conciso***: discorso, ragionamento, serrato | ***Rapido, veloce***: ritmo, tratto serrato | ***Stringente, incalzante***: interrogatorio serrato.

Nel brano, visto il contesto, il senso di serrato è “veloce”.

Comment: Aggiungo: "senza pause", come se fosse qualcosa di chiuso senza  fessure

Comment: @MrPk: A pensarci bene, quando in precedenza avevo qualche volta visto l'espressione "parlare fitto", sempre avevo pensato che quelle che erano "fitte" erano le parole: ciò mi rende l'idea di un parlare senza pause.