# Significato di "parlare a labbra strette"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> «Di dov’è?» chiesi. «Com’è finita alla Rocca? E perché la chiamate così?».
>    
>         «Non so bene,» rispose «e lei **parla a labbra strette**, la principessa. Dicono ch’è una di su, e stava a Sondalo ma
>   gli altri malati non ce l’hanno voluta. E che prima ballava alla Scala. A me pare una sciantosa. Del resto se ne
>   dicono tante...».

Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire la locuzione "parlare a labbra strette" che appare in questo passaggio? Ho cercato alla voce "labbro" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo. Ha qualcosa a che vedere con  [questo](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9096/707)?

Answer (score 2):

In questo caso l’espressione parlare a labbra strette ha un senso dispregiativo ed indica un atteggiamento percepito come altero e snob.

Puoi trovare un riferimento nella definizione di [contegnoso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/contegnoso/):

> ***contegnóso*** agg. [der. di contegno]. – 1. Riferito a persona, che si
>   atteggia o si comporta con serietà, contegno, alterigia: *se ne stava
>   in disparte, tutto c.; le signore guardavano c., colle labbra strette*
>   (Verga).

Infatti la persona in questione viene anche definita “principessa” e “sciantosa”.

Comment: Si dice anche "Parlare a denti stretti" (o a denti serrati) ovvero con tono rabbioso e ostile.